# Open Office Slow Save

Tags: openoffice-writer

I have a 500 page work history (only 330 kb) that I like to keep so I can search for things I've done.

When I used Word 2000, its format, and a regular hard drive it took 1 second to save.

Now with a SSD and Open Office it takes 15 seconds.  It maxes out one of my CPU cores even if I just added a single character to the file.

I'm using Open Document Text format. Is this the best one?
Open Office 3.4.1.

I gave Open Office more RAM (128mb), but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Having Open Office save it in Word 97/2000 format is the fastest solution I've found.  The load time is slower, but the saving is down to two seconds.